# Newbe need to be Pointed in the right direction

Tags: java, android, android-intent

hi again
have bent my head on getting this to work for 3 days now.
The serviceBinder is always NULL when i select picture in Share menu. 
I debug this with LogCat, stepping the code.. and see no obvious error. Also the bindService return false. I have a service class but think the hickup is here somewhere.
Please point me in the right direction!

```
package com.example.ptpp;

public class ServicesDemo extends Activity {

 private MyService serviceBinder = null;
 private static final String TAG = "ServicesDemo";
 boolean mIsBound;
 ServiceConnection mConnection = null;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));

  Intent intent = getIntent();
  Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
  final String mimeType = intent.getType();
  String action = intent.getAction();

   mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

  public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
   serviceBinder = ((MyService.MyBinder) service).getService();
   }
   public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
    serviceBinder = null;
   }
  };

  Intent bindIntent = new Intent(ServicesDemo.this, MyService.class);
  bindService(bindIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
  mIsBound = true; 

  if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action)) {
   if (extras.containsKey(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
    Uri uri = (Uri)extras.getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM); 
    try {
     if(serviceBinder != null)
     // here i call my service to do stuff with the 
                                        //picture i got from "share" menu
     serviceBinder.addAttachment(mimeType, uri, false);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return;
   } else if (extras.containsKey(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {

     return;
   }
  } 
 }
 void doUnbindService() {
  if (mIsBound) {
   // Detach our existing connection.
   unbindService(mConnection);
   mIsBound = false;
  }
 }

 protected void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  doUnbindService();
 }
}
```

package com.example.ptpp;

public class MyService extends Service {

```
private static final String TAG = "MyService";

private final IBinder binder = new MyBinder();
private ServicesDemo callingActivity = null; 

public void setActivity(ServicesDemo i) {
    callingActivity = i;
}
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return binder;
}

public class MyBinder extends Binder {
    MyService getService() {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}

public void onCreate() {

}

public void onDestroy() {


}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {

}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void addAttachment(String mimeType, Uri uri, boolean b) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

}
```

}

Comment: sorry for the bad format but it was nice when i put it in.
And im really suck at android but Java is not new to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem is right here:

```
bindService(bindIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
  mIsBound = true;
```

Binding to a service is asynchronous. You're not guaranteed to be bound after the call to bindService() returns.

Comment: What happen inside the service, i thought Services was synchronous.

Comment: Code run inside a service is run on the main thread, but the creating of the service is asynchronous. That's exactly why there's the onBind() callback.

Comment: My plan is when i start my phone and take a picture. The picture is
silently send to my pc back home. Like a backup think..!
Also the picture is saved normal on  the phone. Kind of a nice little project i think. Must just wrap my head around if Services or something else is the better to use

Comment: What happen in the Service, is it like a thread, i have to keep it busy or it die? As you see I dot do that so maybe thats why the serviceBinder=null

Comment: Well I have no idea what's best to use. The answer to your problem though is that you have to wait for the callback before your service is bound.

Comment: No, you don't have to keep your service busy, and it's not run on a thread. It depends how you're starting it. If you start it with bindService(), it dies when there are no more activities bound to it. If you start it with startService(), it only dies when it calls stopSelf() or stopService() is called on it. Your serviceBinder is null because you're using it before it gets bound.

Comment: ok yea Callback. so i could set some kind of delay after bindService(bindI... and test something to see if its alive

Comment: No, don't do that. It might never connect. Call the code you want to do on the service in the callback. Actually, it's guaranteed never to come back. Nothing will happen until you return from onCreate(). You should read up on the lifecycle of a service, you have a lot of errors here.

Comment: thank you for clearing this up - Thats why i selected Services since they can be started with startService() like that

Comment: yea your right i must read more. Can i ask! The onCreate() is called many times, every time phone/app state change. And i have the creation of the ServiceConnection() there. Is it created again and again?

Comment: Every time your activity is created, a new serviceconnection instance is created as well. But this has nothing to do with your service. In fact, it's necessary because if a new activity is created, it also has to bind to the service of course. I would move the declaration of the serviceconnection up to where the definition is now. But it should be fine in onCreate(). Again, this seems to show a lack of understanding of the lifecycle. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lcycles

Comment: thank you, i started with android 2 weeks ago so have faith :)

Comment: was thinking! Like you could register a buttenclick receiver is it possible from the Share menu in the camera to send the same signal, instead of this Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action). Or how is people doing this. Do you know?

Comment: Its working now btw not sure what i did except move the declaration of the serviceconnection up to where the definition is now

Comment: I thought i could make all this run "hidden" like a background Service - silentely this Service (client) would connect to my PC server waiting for incoming. I read the Service class api dock and cant see any description how to do that. Do I really have to use an Activity class to launch my Service. I know i can launch activity classes from the service if I need.

Comment: You'll either need an activity class to launch your service, or register a broadcast receiver to start it when it receives certain broadcasts. This is a pretty different question though, you should probably ask a new question.

Comment: yea You you right, got sidetracked because we have snowstorm in Sweden
Will post new

Comment: adm can you clean up i created a new Quesion about the above..

"thought i could make all this run "hidden" like a background Service - silentely this Service (client) would connect to my PC server waiting for "